# "Run" command disabled for Particle iOS Cloud SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I want to create a mobile app on iPhone that uses Particle.io's iOS Cloud SDK to read a variable from my Internet Button's Photon.

Particle's [Getting Started documentation](https://docs.particle.io/reference/ios/#getting-started) says to download  the [Particle iOS Cloud SDK example app](https://github.com/spark/spark-sdk-ios/archive/master.zip). I did this, opened the project's .xcworkspace, it builds on Xcode 7.3.1 on MacBook Pro running OS X, but "Run" command is dimmed out for iPhone6+ actual or simulator.

The menu item Product > Run is dimmed out, even after Clean and Build.
In Project Manager, the file "ParticleSDKTests.xctest" is shown in red.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the project's framework target is selected. Because it's only a framework, there's nothing to "run". You'll need to click the scheme selector and pick the application target (called "Spark-SDK") to have anything to run. See the screenshot below:

[image: Xcode scheme selector]

Comment: And, I then had to do chmod +x for each .sh file that requirement permission.